# Architect Predictive Search on 30-50K objects?

Tags: java, angular, caching, search, microservices

I have to build a search functionality where GUI will provide a search field to search objects in Oracle database. There are currently 30K objects I have to search on but they will grow in number over time. 300-400 per month approx.

As a part of the requirement, when user types in any text in search Like for example "ABC", then all objects in the DB that contains ABC should appear in a datatable more like system is predicting results based on what user has types in the search field.

Question is how to architect such feature?

Simple way to do is to load everything in the GUI Javascript object and run search on it. Since JS is ridiculously fast, performance wont be an  issue.

Another way is to run query in the Database everytime user types in text in search field. This does not seem convenient as it will put unnecessary load on the database.

Is there a better way to architect this feature? Please share thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

premature optimization is seldom useful.

300-400 object growth per month with a 30k base object is nothing at all for any DB to handle.

loading all 30k object at once on the browser is awful and may affect performance while querying result in the DB will not have this problem until you have LOT of and LOT of users accessing the DB.

You should be building the service using the Database and then if/when you reach a bottleneck you can think about optimization trick such as caching frequent queries on the database.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand correctly you are suggesting to make a service calls automatically while is typing search text and display results accordingly.

Comment: not while typing; that's for autocomplete when you already have data for example.Think more in term of how google search work

Comment: makes sense. I had proposed this idea before. Architects don't listen! :D thank you.